# How to display different footer depending on the path in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How to display different footers depending on the path? My current best try is this:

```
<template name="appLayout">
  <main role="main">
    {{> _header}}
    {{> yield}}
    {{#if Router.current().route.getName() = "sell-jewelry" }}
    {{> _minifooter}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#else}}
    {{> _footer}}
    {{/else}}
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: See you? I removed all of the nonsense from your question, formed the remains and tried to make it more understable. How about this? Do you think it looks now better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer. This is what you need to do instead:

```
<template name="appLayout">
  <main role="main"
  {{> _header}}
    {{> yield}}
    {{#if isActiveRoute regex='selljewelry'}}
    {{> _minifooter}}
    {{else}}
    {{> _footer}}
    {{/if}}
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: It is wonderful that you answered your own question! You can also accept it (by clicking the green pipe on the left). It is needed, it informs the googlers of the future that this question _has_ an accepted answer.